# Only registered users can see part of the contents of single.php

Tags: php, users, registered

On my wordpress blog, I want a part of single.php to be visible only to registered users.

For example:

```
/code/<?php the_title(); ?>/code/
```

Is there a function that works on a php basis?
What should I do instead of /code/ ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you only want logged in users to be able to see a part of your code you need two things:

- a standard `if` statement
- A function to test is a user is logged in or not aka `is_user_logged_in()`

Note that if a user is not logged in there is no way to know if they are or aren't registered.

Additionally, you can't cache your site for logged in users if you do this or the parts you're hiding will be cached and shown to logged out users. You also won't be able to serve cached pages to logged in users or they'll be unable to see the parts of the page you hid